# Install Glassfish On Eclipse showing Error No repository found

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

when i am trying to install the glassfish on Eclips i am facing two issues:

1- I can not find it when i click on create new server under oracle folder ..
[image]

2- when i am trying to install the glassfish tool from the market it gives me a message that says *No repository*

3- when even going to add the link manually under available software. it gives me the same error No Repository Found

I am Using Eclipse Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0)
JDK : 16
JRE :jre1.8.0_311

what could be the issue?

Answer (score 4):

The Glassfish Tools project and it's dependency Eclipse Sapphire have been both archived, but the repos should be working anyway. Glassfish Tools repo is not working though, but both projects have been bundled in Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse, which has it's own repo available by default in eclipse 21-12 (and many more versions before that one).

Go to Help -> Install new software and find the repo as shown in the image.

[image: Oracle Enterprisa Pack for Eclipse repo]

Answer (score 3):

For those who don't want to try to type the above:

Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse 12.2.1.8 Dependences - http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.2.1.8/oxygen/repository/dependencies/